# CSS buttons in a row strange space

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to display two buttons in a row with an image on them. I use:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tab">
    <button>
       <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
      </button>
    <button>
       <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    Test123
  </div>
</div>
```

Code works fine but why is there a space of 1px at the bottom line of red border? Moreover, how can I also erase the red space between the two buttons?

[image]

Comment: You should specify your browser, because in Chrome there is no mentioned 1px bottom margin.

Comment: Ι use Chrome and it gives the above result...

Comment: Run the snippet I've added to your question, does it show the same as your picture?

Comment: Um, no =| the space between is the same though

Comment: button{  border:none;} would solve the 1px red space at bottom

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't debug code remotely :) Perhaps, your html code differs somehow. Btw, your `.outer` `<div>` didn't have closing tag.

Comment: Yes, I closed it. It's the exact same... Edited my code...

Comment: add `display: block` to the `img` or use `vertical-align: top` to remove the *gap below the image*... see the duplicates for removing *space between inline elements*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove white spaces between buttons: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0ose31La/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="tab">
        <button>
            <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
        </button><button>
            <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Test123
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work... But why xd

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tricks to remove space between elements with `display: inline-block`, but the most easy is *"just float them"*.

Let's add `float: left` to buttons, put them into their own container: `<div class="buttons">...</div>` and apply [`clearfix` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) to it.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab {
  background-color: red;
}

.buttons button {
  float: left;
}
 
.buttons:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>
      <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
      </button>
      <button>
     <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      Test123
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `font-size:0;` to `.tab` class because button tag take by default `display:inline-block`. and you can also use `float:left` and `clearfix`.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outer {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px;
}
.inner {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
.tab {
    background-color: red;
    font-size:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="tab">
        <button>
            <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
        </button>
        <button>
            <img src="http://www.insideredbox.com/images/ball_red.png">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Test123
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```